# How can I run a Kubernetes pod with the sole purpose of running exec against it?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, command-line-interface

Please before you comment or answer, this question is about a CLI program, not a service. Apparently 90% of Kubernetes has to do with running services, so there is sparse documentation for CLI programs meant to be part of a pipeline workflow.

I have a command line program that uses stdout for JSON results.

I have a docker image for the command line program.

If I create the container as a Kubernetes Job, than stdout and stderr are mixed and require heuristic scrubbing to get pure JSON out.

The stderr messages are from native libraries outside of my direct control.

Supposedly, if I run `kubectl exec` against a running pod, I will get the normal stdout/stderr pipes.

Is there a way to just have the pod running without an entrypoint (or some dummy service entrypoint) with the sole purpose of running `kubectl exec` against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to just have the pod running without an entrypoint [...]?

A pod consists of one or more containers, each of which has an individual entrypoint.  It is certainly possible to run a *container* with a dummy command, for example, you can build an image with:

```
CMD sleep inf
```

This will run a container that will persist until you kill it, and you could happily `docker exec` into it.

You can apply the same solution to k8s.  You could build an image as described above and deploy that in a pod, or you could use an existing image and simply set the command, as in:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myexistingimage
    command: ["sleep", "inf"]
```

Comment: Works great! Sure wish I could just use Job though

Answer (score 0):

You can use kubectl as docker cli https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/

`kubectl run` just do the job. There is no need for a workaround.

Aditionally, you can attach I/O and disable automatic restart:

```
kubectl run -i -t busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never
```

Comment: Attaching a TTY would restrict the I/O to inside the container, which is not what I want. I know about `kubectl run`, I'm working on that now, but it's not working with the `overrides` JSON I'm giving it for some reason. I specifically wanted to know what Iarsks explained

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30645 Hmm is using run with volumes even possible?

Comment: Ok, attaching TTY is optional, without it the container run default comand  or entrypoint and stop.

Comment: Example, I use it to run some tests and when it finished I explore the logs using `kubectl logs busybox*` and results in the pod using `kubectl exec -ti busybox sh`. You can't mount volumes using `kubectl run` but you can use `kubectl cp` to get files from the pod to your computer